# How can Install Vlocity DataPack (Explore & Checkout using Digital Commerce LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, sdk, omnistudio, vlocity

I need to install Vlocity Data Pack "Explore & Checkout using Digital Commerce LWC"

but when i click next button to install it, it gives me "Import Error & Invalid Data".

Also i need to ask is it require to purchase CPQ license to access digital commerce sample app??
[image: Omnistudio DataPacks]

Comment: Can you try installing from [here](https://success.vlocity.com/s/login/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fs%2Finstall-data-pack%3Flibrary%3DaBQo0000000PAsRGAW%26id%3DaBS3m000000CbexGAC)

Answer (score 0):

As Vinay pointed out, you need go to that Vlocity [download link](https://success.vlocity.com/s/install-data-pack?library=aBQo0000000PAsRGAW&id=aBS3m000000CbexGAC) (assuming you already have a login).

Then read the "Configuration Requirements".

```
Configuration Requirements
- Create offers with prices and add them to catalogs.
- Install the latest CME 109 package.
- Install OmniScripts and deploy them.
- (Optional) Configure Attribute-Based Pricing (ABP)
- Run CMT administration jobs (cached API jobs)
- Install the below artifacts required to run this process:
   - Checkout VIP MultiPack: Datapack file containing VIP for Checkout Process
   - DC OOTB LWC Templates: ZIP file containing HTML and meta.xml files of corresponding DC LWCs in a managed package
   - DX Data File: DX file containing data to be imported into org to run Sample DC LWC App
   - Reference Documents
   - Refer the documents attached in the “Supplementary Files” section for additional information on the solution, installation & setup, and configuration.
Vlocity Install DataPack Instructions- DataPack installation guide
VPL Digital Commerce Artefacts Installation Guide (DC LWC Only)  - Instructions to install checkout datapack and other related artifacts
```

It doesn't state any pre-requisites of CPQ license.

If you could follow the [Vlocity Install DataPack Guide](https://success.vlocity.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P3m000011z4DoEAI&) and tell us where exactly which step you got the error otherwise it is near impossible to help you.